# How to make expand/collapse in bootstrap 3 stricly horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 3. My idea is to expand/collapse some words between other words (transcriptions in dictionary) by clicking on one button.

Words and transcriptions between them all have class `display: "inline-block"`. It's there a way to make strictly horizontal transition, and avoid this display:"block" part of it? Panel heading should be always in one line. (And avoid to write additional js)

```
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="note">{{note}} </div>
          <div class="word -arabic-text-big">{{word}}</div>
          <div class="collapse transcription">[******]</div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".transcription">
        Transcipt
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the answer was too simple. But before i did something wrong...

```
    .note, .word, .transcription {
    display: inline-block;
}

.transcription.collapse.in {
    display: inline-block;
}
.transcription.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```